# Is Red Star OS released under the GPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl, linux

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_OS), Red Star OS is

> is a North Korean Linux-based operating system

Does that mean it's covered by the GPL, or are there exceptions?

Comment: The source code isn't released... [further reading](http://codemonkey.org.uk/2011/06/01/red-star-kernel/)

Comment: Why would the fact that it's North Korean change the license of the kernel or any of the GPL components on which it is based

Comment: Just want to say that GPL has never required folks to publish code online. The reason people do so is because it's the easiest (cheapest) way to comply with the license. For example, a publisher of GPL software is not obligated to supply source code to everyone in the world.

Comment: Does North Korea even recognize copyright for software? If it doesn't, then there's no copyright license violation, since there is no copyright.

Comment: And even if *does* recognize copyright for software, is there a treaty between North Korea and the US about mutual recognition of copyright?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: You mean all software  North Korea produces is public domain?  Right.  *[goes to look for free North Korean software]*

Comment: Some other thoughts: would you really want to be anywhere near this software when it explodes?  Or, like, ever?

Comment: No, not necessarily. If your country universally recognizes copyright on software, then all software, including North Korean, is copyrighted in your country. OTOH, if North Korea universally does not recognize copyright on software, then all software is not copyrighted in North Korea. Or, North Korea could pass a law that all software produced in North Korea is copyrighted, but foreign software isn't. Copyright is a national matter, every country can do as it pleases. There are multilateral treaties, but AFAIK North Korea hasn't signed any of them, so aren't bound by them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parties_to_international_copyright_agreements), the DPRK is signatory of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), which includes things such as mutual copyright recognition and minimum copyright terms.

Comment: This might be a good topic for the newly proposed [Open Source Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source?referrer=LYVOhcyWjB2btmuqLjy44w2) which is currently seeking people to commit to it so it can go into beta.

Comment: @durron597 under the terms of the GPL, if you have a binary copy then don't you have the right to a copy of the source?

Comment: @amon: I didn't know that. However, still Berne only requires that works created in other countries be treated no worse than works created in the home country. Which means that if North Korea doesn't have copyright on North Korean computer programs, then not recognizing the copyright of Linux is not a violation, since it isn't treating Linux worse than its own software. Mandatory copyright on software is a part of the WIPO Copyright Treaty (and also TRIPS, I believe), neither of which North Korea has signed.

Comment: @Alison: only if computer programs can be copyrighted. If computer programs can't be copyrighted, then you don't need a copyright license, and thus don't need to abide by its terms. North Korea *has* signed the Berne Convention, which means that is *must* extend its own copyright to works created in other signatory countries, but it has *not* signed the WIPO Copyright Treaty or TRIPS, which would require it to implement copyright for computer programs. Since it isn't forced by international treaty, it is at least conceivable that it simply doesn't have copyright for software.

Comment: However, Article 9 of the DPRK Copyright Law *does* include computer programs in the list of protected works, so that speculation is moot. Rather, it is simply a license violation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 9):

As a Linux derivate, it *should* be licensed under the GNU GPL, but it isn't. That means that by distributing it under a different license, the KCC is violating the copyright of thousands of Linux contributors.

However, that does not mean that someone who obtained a copy of it can redistribute it under GPL, as that would also be a copyright violation, in this case of the copyright of the modifications the KCC did. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Good luck, however, with fighting a copyright lawsuit across the border of North-Korea.

Comment: As a derivative work, isn't it implicitly GPL'd?

Comment: @Alison No, it is not. You can't force someone else to distribute their work under your terms. You can only force them to stop distributing your work under terms you didn't agree to.

Comment: @Alison Also, when you receive GPL software withouth the GPL attached, you don't have the right to redistribute it, because it was never licensed to *you*. (GPL does not imply that it is licensed to *everyone*, by the way)

Comment: The GPL is based on US/EU/etc. law, and agreements between countries concerning copyright.  North Korea neither has these copyright laws, nor does it have these agreements.  Hence, suing them would be a non-starter as they have broken no laws.

Comment: @StevenBurnap That's wrong. North Korea has signed the Berne Convention and has local copyright laws which forbid this. However, the KCC is a government entity, and suing a government entity in a dictatorship is quite futile.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding would be: if you come into possession of copy of the Red Star Linux kernel (at least), then it legally must give you the rights enumerated under the GPL.

There is, however, no requirement that they allow you to come into possession of it.

The more usual example of this is internal corporate software. It might be built in such a way as to violate the GPL, e.g. incorporating non-GPL bits, but if it's never distributed to anyone, the GPL is powerless.

Another example: a web application, like, say, GMail, might never be actually distributed to anyone. (Thus the need for the AGPL.)

There are ethical debates about whether loading a non-GPL kernel module causes the running kernel to violate the GPL, but they also aren't distributed.

The GPL itself also explicitly exempts aggregation — so even if it's using a Linux kernel, it could be built to require non-GPL software to be useful.

Android is a bit like that, in most cases; you don't gain GPL rights to, e.g. the pre-loaded Facebook Katana application or radio chip set drivers.

(Not a lawyer and not particularly familiar with this OS)